# Ruby Rails total value of loop each

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a loop like this listing all count numbers like 2,44,11 etc., how do I calculate total number?

```
<% @book.each do |book| %>
<div><%= book.count %></div>
<% end %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@books.sum`, and pass it a proc which is invoked for each record, returning the number you want to add to the sum. Using `Proc#to_sym` gives you a very succinct syntax:

```
@books.sum(&:count)
```

---

```
<% @book.each do |book| %>
<div><%= book.count %></div>
<% end %>

Total books: <%= @books.sum(&:count) %>
```

Comment: sorry im newb where should i put this ? inside of the loop ?

Comment: No, just wherever you want to get the sum of counts. See update.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) to add up the `count`s and get the total count of all the books:

```
@book.inject(0) { |total, book| total + book.count }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@book.collect(&:count).sum
```

Answer (score 1):

try it out `@books.sum(:count)` this will return you sum